# Analytics - how to tell where converted traffic came from?

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads

I must be missing something obvious. I have Analytics set up with conversion tracking (goals), and I had 4 customers complete the goals yesterday. I'm trying to find out where those 4 customers came from (organic search? if organic, what keywords? etc) but I can't figure out how to do that in Adwords. When I click into the goal tracking overview, I see my 4 customers and it breaks it down so I see that 3 of them came from adwords (cpc) and 1 of them came from organic. I'd like to know exactly what ads brought the traffic and what keywords on the organic search led them to me.

How can I do this?

It seems like a simple request... but I can't figure it out... thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your dashboard on the left side click

1. Traffic Source
2. Sources
3. All Traffic

Then at the top of the chart you'll see "Site Usage" to the right of this you should see the name of your goal (Goal 1) I have now in the table below you can see your Source/Medium of your websites traffic and the Goal conversion rates in the table as well

Comment: I think this is part of the answer, but not all of it. I've looked where you told me to look, and now I have a table showing that goal traffic of 2.54% came from google/cpc and 14.29% is google/organic. Now: how can I see exactly how many visits that is for each, and exactly what ad (or keywords) got the user to my site?

Comment: Near the top is a button Visits vs Select Metric, so select Goal Set 1 and Goal Conversion rate, now the chart has two lines one showing quantity of visits the other your conversion rate. For AdWords data under Traffic -> Sources click Campaigns and set your goal conversion rate, Adwords keyword, Campaign or Ad Copy your have all the options here to see AdWords data vs Visits vs Conversions

Comment: I have the chart with the two lines, but I'm still not able to see where my organic goal completion traffic came from. I can go to "Campaigns" and figure out how to see the keywords and ads that converted-- thank you for that. So how do I get my organic keywords that converted?

Comment: @Eric Traffic Source -> Sources -> Organic, then at the very top click your Goal name you'll see the organic keywords which converted.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Long Tail Magic](http://www.longtailmagic.com/) ... Thats what it does. It works well for me and my clients. Consider it as a real time, stupid simple analytics tool that you install on your server (big thing for my clients).

Answer (score 0):

use Google URL builder to add tracking to your URLS

Comment: URL builder is for tagging links that you control. In my case, my conversions are coming from AdWords (which auto-tags the links) and Google organic search (which Analytics is smart enough to call out separately).