# How can I see in Google Analytics where my users came from?

Tags: google-analytics, referrer

I am using Google Analitics and struggling to find where my users came from. I can see demographics (country / city) information, but struggling to find what site have they came from.

I found this [answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/28988/30526):

> From your dashboard on the left side click
>
> - Traffic Source
> - Sources
> - All Traffic

But can not see this on my left side. It has

- Dashboards
- Shortcuts
- Intelligence Events
- Real-Time
- Audience
- Acquisition
- Behavior
- Conversions

Can someone help me?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/user/googleanalytics

Comment: what do you mean by "where"? Is it sites referring or what?

Comment: By where I mean what site sent them to my site. For example a person clicked on the link on site A and it brought them to my site.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can find the referrals under `Acquisition` , in `All Trafic` and `All Referrals` reports.

[image: All Traffic and All Referrals reports]

Comment: Cool thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for.